# Creating an XML file based on a ListView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview

I want to create an XML file based on a ListView. Right now I'm creating an Bitmap of a ListView, making it a drawable and then setting it as the background of a relative layout. Like this...

```
 public Bitmap getWholeListViewItemsToBitmap() {
    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.hourList);
    line.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    line.buildDrawingCache();
    line.layout(0, 0, line.getMeasuredWidth(), line.getMeasuredHeight());
    Bitmap linebmp = line.getDrawingCache().copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false);
    ListAdapter adapter = listview.getAdapter();
    int itemscount = adapter.getCount();
    int allitemsheight = 0;
    List<Bitmap> bmps = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < itemscount; i++) {

        View childView = adapter.getView(i, null, listview);

        childView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listview.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

        childView.layout(0, 0, childView.getMeasuredWidth(), childView.getMeasuredHeight());
        childView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        childView.buildDrawingCache();

        bmps.add(childView.getDrawingCache());

        allitemsheight+=childView.getMeasuredHeight();
        allitemsheight+=line.getMeasuredHeight();
    }

    allitemsheight-=line.getMeasuredHeight();
    Bitmap bigbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(listview.getMeasuredWidth(), allitemsheight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas bigcanvas = new Canvas(bigbitmap);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    int iHeight = 0;
     // This is where the Bitmap is created
    for (int i = 0; i < bmps.size(); i++) {
        Bitmap bmp = bmps.get(i);
        bigcanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, iHeight, paint);
        bigcanvas.drawBitmap(linebmp, 0, iHeight, paint);
        iHeight += bmp.getHeight();
        iHeight += linebmp.getHeight();

        bmp.recycle();
        bmp = null;
    }

    return bigbitmap;
}
```

I'm getting a Bitmap of each list in the ListView and then putting them together in one big Bitmap (with lines in between). This is the result...

[image: result]

But such a large image loaded in the memory causes a lot of lag... So I was wondering how you could do something similar but with XML layouts. And if it's possible I'd like each Item in the ListView to get added in an individual view/item in the XML layout. So I can hide or show each item depending on different factors.

If you have any suggestions, they are very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to dynamically build a View? Drawing a ListView bitmap seems like a strange thing to do.

Comment: @cricket_007 dynamically create an xml layout

Comment: XML layouts are static resources that are inflated into ViewGroups. What is preventing you from building a `LinearLayout` and using the `addView` method?

Comment: @cricket_007 Many reason, for example I need it to be a background drawable for a relative layout and I need to "create" and make changes to the file/image/xml while it's not inflated.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to "dump" a `View` back into it's XML format. You are welcome to extend the `View` class and implement your own functionality and try to serialize that in some manner.