# XML Drawables Created Programmatically Doesn't Display Properly

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-drawable

I'm trying to turn a `ListView` into a Drawable XML file.
What I've done is that I've turned each `Item` in the `ListView` into a `BitmapDrawable`, made an `array` of them all so I can make a `LayerDrawable` of them and than I set it as the background.

Like this:

```
    ListAdapter adapter = listView.getAdapter();

    View childView1 = adapter.getView(0, null, listView);
    View childView2 = adapter.getView(1, null, listView);
    View childView3 = adapter.getView(2, null, listView);
    View childView4 = adapter.getView(3, null, listView);

    childView1.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    childView1.layout(0, 0, childView1.getMeasuredWidth(), childView1.getMeasuredHeight());

    childView2.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    childView2.layout(0, 0, childView2.getMeasuredWidth(), childView2.getMeasuredHeight());

    childView3.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    childView3.layout(0, 0, childView3.getMeasuredWidth(), childView3.getMeasuredHeight());

    childView4.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    childView4.layout(0, 0, childView4.getMeasuredWidth(), childView4.getMeasuredHeight());

    childView1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    childView1.buildDrawingCache();

    childView2.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    childView2.buildDrawingCache();

    childView3.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    childView3.buildDrawingCache();

    childView4.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    childView4.buildDrawingCache();

    Bitmap bmp1 = childView1.getDrawingCache().copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false);
    Bitmap bmp2 = childView2.getDrawingCache().copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false);
    Bitmap bmp3 = childView3.getDrawingCache().copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false);
    Bitmap bmp4 = childView4.getDrawingCache().copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, false);

    BitmapDrawable bd1 = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp1);
    BitmapDrawable bd2 = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp2);
    BitmapDrawable bd3 = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp3);
    BitmapDrawable bd4 = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp4);

    BitmapDrawable drawables[] = {bd1, bd2, bd3, bd4};

    LayerDrawable wow = new LayerDrawable(drawables);

    root.setBackground(wow);
```

But this is the result.............................................................
[image: Currently]

And this is the goal... (Although only 4 ListItems)
[image]

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Edit: Here is the ListView...

```
    String hi[] = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
    ArrayList<String> hourArray = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(hi));
    hourArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.listitem_forecast, R.id.listitem_forecast_textview, hourArray);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.hourList);
    listView.setAdapter(hourArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: All this makes **no sense** to me.

Comment: You can edit your previous question to bump it to the front page. This seems to be a repost.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38903526/creating-an-xml-file-based-on-a-listview

Comment: @cricket_007 what do you mean? Should I copy everything and put it underneath the other question... or replace it?

Comment: You're essentially asking the same question, yes? Turning a ListView into an XML drawable. So, yes, you can edit the other question with your current problem implementing that